# php remove curly braces and content inside retrieve remaining

Tags: php, string

want to **remove particular text of php string which is inside braces including braces** it should removed....

## Data string as shown following...

```
{page:header}
this text should not be removed
{menu_list:menu_list_2}
this text should not be removed
{page:footer}
```

want to remove text which is inside curly braces and also curly braces...

## want data like this...

```
this text should not be removed
this text should not be removed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex,

```
$text='{page:header}
this text should not be removed
{menu_list:menu_list_2}
this text should not be removed
{page:footer}'
$data = preg_replace("/\{[^}]+\}/", "", $text);
print_r($data); // answer will be as follow
this text should not be removed
this text should not be removed
```